# How do you place a footer at the bottom of the LAST page when there is dynamic data in the body

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a report which has a requirement that the footer must be placed at the bottom of the last page.  The report body loads dynamically based off how many records are returned from the database.  The report could be 1 page or more.

I have tried using a sticky footer, this is OK for viewing the HTML on the website but when the length of the report is greater than 1 page and when viewing the print preview screen, the footer overlaps with the body of the report and the footer remains on the first page instead of moving to the last page.

Does anyone know of a way to place a footer at the bottom of the last page when creating a printable screen that is properly formatted for a user to print without using a sticky footer.

The sticky footer I implemented did not display properly in the print preview screen when there was multiple pages to print.

Comment: Include some code. Make a fiddle. What have you tried.

Comment: for printing you should make an own stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
#sticky-footer 
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
@media print 
{
    #sticky-footer 
    {
        position: static;
        bottom: auto;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="report-content">...</div>
<div id="sticky-footer">...</div>
```

Comment: implementing the code above, now my footer follows the bottom of the screen as I scroll up and down overlapping my body/header. When I click print, the footer remains positioned underneath the body but not at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Telecaster - HTML / CSS don't really have any concept of printable pages. You have the CSS page-break properties to force breaking, but that doesn't help you place the footer at the bottom of the current printed page http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/pagebreak.shtml

Comment: thanks for your input, I'm going to use a page break to keep the footer portion on a separate page instead of fighting the CSS.